# TransferHttpCacheModule for POST calls

Tags: angular, angular-universal

So I'm creating an Angular Universal SSR site. Fortunately with Angular 15 **TransferHttpCacheModule** is now automatically included.

But I can't believe considering how long that module has been around it can still only handle GET calls and not POST calls. The Back End api I have to work with have some POST calls which require me to send a body in order to get some search results. Is there an alternative library that anyone can recommend? Of course if I disable Javascript I can see the call working properly and printing out on my page. But then it will disappear when Javascript is enabled.

Comment: You can create your own interceptor which implements the logic you need

Comment: @David I’ve made my own interceptor before. But I’m not sure what I would do inside it in order to complete this task. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: You can just look at the code of the TransferHttpCacheModule here: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/modules/common/src/transfer_http.ts